# Is there any isomorphism between these two local rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, local-rings

Are the following two local rings isomorphic for any prime number $p$ and field with p elements, $\mathbb{Z}_p$ :
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_p[X,Y]}{(X^3,XY,Y^2)}\ \text{ and } \frac{\mathbb{Z}_p[X,Y]}{(X^3,X^2-XY,Y^2)}\
\  ?$$

If there is, why is that?

first I  have expected the answer to be no, but I might be wrong, and in any case I don't know how to prove it. Here's what I've tried to prove that these two rings are isomorphic.

I suppose that there is homomorphism like $\varphi$ such that
$$\varphi:   \mathbb{Z}_p[X,Y]\ \rightarrow \frac{\mathbb{Z}_p[X,Y]}{(X^3,X^2-XY,Y^2)}\
\  $$
$$X\mapsto f(X,Y) + I  $$
$$Y\mapsto g(X,Y) + I  $$
such that $f$ and $g$ are polynomials of X and Y in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X,Y]$ and $I = (X^3,X^2-XY,Y^2).$

I want to find right $f$ and $g$ so that $\varphi$ be a surjective ring homomorphism and finaly find the kernel of $\varphi$ to be $J=(X^3,XY,Y^2)$

Comment: Is there a particular reason you expect an isomorphism between these local rings? If so, can you please add it?

Comment: I saw in an article that there are three commutative rings with p^4 elements, characteristic p and some other particular conditions. I find five commutative local rings with same conditions and proved that three of them are not isomorphic. Therefore, I think the remaining two must be isomorphic at least with one of the previous 

@EvansGambit

Comment: Could you please write explicitly in your question that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ refers to *the field with $p$ elements* rather than *the $p$-adic numbers*?

Comment: Editing done @Mindlack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two rings are not isomorphic. An easy way to see this is to note that both rings have a unique maximal ideal generated by (the residue classes of) $X$ and $Y$. Then consider for both rings the ideal of elements that are annihilated by all elements of the maximal ideal. For the first ring it is a 2-dimensional vector space generated by $X^2$ and $Y$ whereas for the second ring it is a 1-dimensional vector space generated by $X^2$. But this property is clearly preserved under isomorphism so the two rings cannot be isomorphic.

Comment: But I fond a bijective homomorphism and I think it is true. also these rings are 4-dimentional vector space over Z_p

Comment: Interesting. What are $X^2$ and $Y$ in the first ring mapped to in the second ring by your isomorphism?

Comment: consider maps X+I to X+Y+J and Y+I to Y+J from the second ring to the first. this mapping is a bijective well defined homomorphism.

Comment: But is this well defined? In the second ring you have $x^2 - xy = 0$. And this is mapped to $(x+y)^2 - (x+y)y = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 - xy - y^2 = x^2 + xy$ which is non-zero in the first ring (since $x^2$ does not belong to $J$).

Comment: yes, you're right. I try another maps but I can't find the right one. could you please explain more about your statement that these two rings are not isomorphic? I don't understand well.

Comment: Sure. I consider the vector space $\{z | xz = yz = 0\}$. Another way to describe this vector space is as $\{z | wz = 0$ whenever $w$ is not invertible$\}$. It is useful to describe it this way, because that means that any isomorphism must map these two vectorspaces isomophically to eachother. However since the vectorspace has dimension 2 in the first ring and dimension 1 in the second, this is not possible. This shows that there can be no isomorphism between the two rings.

Comment: I tried to give an elementary explanation above. But it might be educational to points to some more advanced concepts involved: Both rings are examples of Artinian local rings. The vector space considered above is called the socle of the ring. And the second ring is an example of a Gorenstein ring. It would go to far to explain these concepts here (if you are not already familiar with them) but you might want to explore them on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I’ll be using $\mathbb{F}_p$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and I will show these two rings are not isomorphic.

A morphism $\psi$ from the second ring to the first one coresponds to the datum of two polynomials $f,g \in \mathbb{F}_p[x,y]$ such that $f^3, g^2, f(f-g)\in (x^3,xy,y^2)$.

This means that $f \in (x,y)$ and $g \in (x^2,y)$. Thus $fg \in (x^3,yx,y^2)$, so $f^2 \in (x^3,xy,y^2)$. As we can write $f(x) \in ax+(x^2,y)$, we get $a^2x^2 \in (x^3,xy,y^2)$, thus $a=0$ and $f \in(x^2,y)$.

It follows that the image of $\psi$ is contained $(\mathbb{F}_p+(x^2,y)\mathbb{F}_p[x,y])/(x^3,xy,y^2)$ and in particular $x \notin \mathrm{im}\,\psi$, so that $\psi$ isn’t onto.